# Problem installing Ubuntu on USB drive with "no root file system is defined"

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, usb, live-usb, usb-drive

I am trying to install `Ubuntu Tahr` on a VisionTek USB ssd thumb with 120 GB.  Using `Gparted`, I deleted the old partition and created a new one in fat32.  Then with Startup Disk Creator, I put the Ubuntu iso on it and tried booting from the thumb drive.

Only problem is i come up against the message

```
No Root File System is Defined.  Please correct this from the partitioning menu.
```

When I try clicking on the change button or plus, the page freezes.

I tried formatting the thumb drive as `ext4`  Same results.  Tried using unetbootin but that didn't even see my thumb drive.  Tried lili usb creator from windows.  Same results.  Tried Lubuntu, same results.  Tried

```
sudo apt-get remove dmraid
```

during the live Ubuntu.  Same thing.

Funny thing is I can get into the live Ubuntu but I can't seem to install it.  My laptop doesn't have an internal hard drive or any other usb plugged into it at the time, aside from the ssd and the charger.  I am ready to tear my hair out.  Please don't let me become bald.

Comment: Just to make that clear: you are booting to live USB and want to install Ubuntu on **another** USB (because you won't be able to install on the USB you booted from)?

Comment: mbr or uefi based configuration? also usb creator is broken imo and switch to efi is so worth

Comment: Ah, no.  I tried it with 2 usb drives yesterday, one with the installer and another to work as the root file.  The installer didn't see the thumb ssd.  Gparted in live could see it though.  Then I tried formatting both again in another computer and trying the installation again.  And it worked.  Thanks for helping me out!  :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Select the Partition in which  You need to install.
- Unallocate it by clicking the  **-** sign.
- Create Partition of EXT 4
- Remember to Set the  **/** in the last option of Partition Creation.
- Continue to Install

Comment: The symbol   /   is known as the root of the file system of ext type.

Comment: Yeah, after the installer could see both usb drives, I did this too.  Thanks very much :)

Comment: If still having problem with boot then try,    /boot